# jQuery update text field not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm trying to calculate a cost dynamically by entering quantities and costs in text fields, doing the math and returning the value to a `<label>`. I'm sending the results to the console and everything is fine, but when I update the value to the `<label>` element, it displays this: "[object Window]". The code is as follows:

```
function updateCost(){
    var numUF = $("#numUF").val();
    var costUF = $("#costUF").val();
    var numDBT = $("#numDBT").val();
    var costDBT = $("#costDBT").val();
    var numDMT = $("#numDMT").val();
    var costDMT = $("#costDMT").val();
    var numTr = $("#numTr").val();
    var costTr = $("#costTr").val();

    var valorCotiza = (numUF * costUF) + (numDBT * costDBT) + (numDMT * costDMT) + (numTr * costTr);
    $("#valorCotiza").text("$ " + toString(valorCotiza));
    console.log(valorCotiza);
}
```

The HTML part of this is

```
<div class="item">
    <label class="H5">Valor total cotización:</label><br />
    <label id="valorCotiza">$</label>
    <br /><br />
    <label class="H5">Valor IVA: (16%)</label><br />
    <label id="valorIVA">$</label>
</div>
```

Any ideas about what could be going wrong?
BTW, its a PhoneGap proyect, and I'm using jQuery.

Comment: What is console log printing?

Comment: It's printing the result of the operation, ie: 3500

Comment: How about if you ignore the toString function and only put the valorCotiza value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `toString(valorCotiza)` particular code is equals to `window.toString(valorCotiza)` in a regular environment. And this will return `"[object Window]"`. So the below code is enough for doing your task.

```
$("#valorCotiza").text("$ " + valorCotiza);
```

A simple concatenation is enough to change a number to string. No need to do it explicitly. If you still want to do it in that way, then use the `Number.prototype.toString()`. That can be used like,

```
$("#valorCotiza").text("$ " + valorCotiza.toString());
```

Comment: @ChristianRodriguez Glad to help! :) Try to press the tick mark present inside anyone of the answers here which helped you to solve your issue. And this is not a compulsion. :)

Comment: It won't let me for another 2 minutes :S

Answer (score 0):

Use `String(valorCotiza)`. Using `toString()` gives a String representation of the window (as you've seen).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
valorCotiza.toString()
```

to get the number converted to string. You must use it if you want a string when not doing a concat operation with a string. In your case particularly, your concatenation operation("$" + valorCotiza) should do it.